# Adding condition to average time within another sheet

Tags: google-sheets

Trying to add an additional condition to average time within another sheet.

This formula works currently to pull the average time within a range

'''=ARRAYFORMULA(AVERAGE(VALUE(TEXT("00"&Interaction_Data!R3:R,"hh:mm:ss"))))'''

I need to add an if condition to only average the rows that also contain "Partner 1" within the range C3:C of the "Interaction_Data" sheet

I have tried this following formula as I thought this would do it but it returns error #N/A
'''=ArrayFormula(if(AVERAGE(VALUE(TEXT("00"&Interaction_Data!R3:R,"hh:mm:ss")),Interaction_Data!C3:C,"partner 1")))'''

I feel like I have tried all other positions for the If statement, range and criteria but I have obviously missed the one that will work.

Any help will be awesome please

Comment: Use `AVERAGEIF()` function.

Comment: Can you provide a copy of the spreadsheet, showing the desired output?

Comment: Thanks @Harun24hr due to the value(text part of this formula I am unsure how to add in the new range and criteria. Do you have any ideas?

Comment: @Iamblichus I will mock up something shareable shortly to support and test this further

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`AVERAGEIF` does not work with `ARRAYFORMULA`. Use `QUERY` instead.

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(QUERY(
{VALUE(TEXT("00"&Interaction_Data!R3:R,"hh:mm:ss")),Interaction_Data!C3:C},
"select avg(Col1) where Col2='partner 1' label avg(Col1) ''"))
```

Comment: Thank you, it took a while to Google sheets to generate but it does work perfectly an help me to better understand how queries work. Thank you so much :)